# adding an iframe to rmd overwrites the whole document font size

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, knitr, bookdown

I want to write a report in rmarkdown which includes one html file (which is saved before) in cloud r studio. However, when I include the chunk of code to show the html, the whole document font size is overwritten to the smallest (after knitting).

Here is my code for an example document:

`````
---
title: "Name"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  bookdown::html_document2:
    config:
      fontsettings:
        size: 5
# bibliography: main.bib
link_citations: yes
csl: apa.csl
editor_options:
  markdown:
    wrap: sentence
---

there is a paragraph here!


````{=html}
```{r results='asis'}
xfun::file_string('esc_all.html')
```
````
`````

Here are the links for downloading the html file ([esc_all.htm](https://github.com/zahra-arjm/wikipedia_discussions/blob/main/docs/esc_all.html)), and [apa.csl](https://github.com/zahra-arjm/wikipedia_discussions/blob/main/docs/apa.csl).

Any ideas?

Comment: That's probably because you include a complete HTML document. You should only include the content inside `<body></body>`.

Comment: @YihuiXie Thanks for the comment. I tried it with only the [<body> tag](https://github.com/zahra-arjm/wikipedia_discussions/blob/rmd/body.html) and another time with only the text [inside the <body> tag](https://github.com/zahra-arjm/wikipedia_discussions/blob/rmd/inside_body.html), there will be no iframe but the font size won't change. When including the [<head> tag](https://github.com/zahra-arjm/wikipedia_discussions/blob/rmd/body_and_head.html), it shows the iframe and the graph, but the font size will be overwritten.